# How to call a preference return type method of an apex controller class to a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

//This is my controller class, from this class I am not getting a coverage of convertLead() in to my test class.

```
public with sharing class LeadConversionController
{
        public Lead leadSource {get;set;}
        public Boolean createOpp {get;set;}
        public String strAccountId {get;set;}
        public Lead leadObj{get; set;}
        public Contact contact {get;set;}
        public List<SelectOption> lstCompanies{get; set;}


        public LeadConversionController(ApexPages.StandardController scMain)
        {
            contact=new Contact();

            lstCompanies = new List<SelectOption>();
            leadSource = [SELECT Id, Check_For_Account_On_Conversion__c, FirstName, LastName, OwnerId, Company,Status, Street, City, State, PostalCOde, Country, Phone, Fax FROM Lead WHERE Id = :scMain.getId()];
            System.debug('values:' +leadSource);
            getlstCompanyInfo();
            convertLead();
            createOpp = false;  
        }



        //To get Account related and Company name information from Lead to Lead Conversion Page.
        public List<SelectOption> getlstCompanyInfo()
        {
            String strCompanyWildcard = '%' + leadSource.Company + '%';

            List<Account> lstAcct = [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :strCompanyWildcard];
            //Picklist to get the option of Creating a new account or using an existing one.


            // Add New Account if not found
            lstCompanies.add(new SelectOption('1','Create New Account: ' + leadSource.Company));
            // Add found Accounts to SelectList
            for(Account accObj : lstAcct) 
            {
                lstCompanies.add(new SelectOption(accObj.Id, 'Attach to Existing: ' + accObj.Name + ' (' + accObj.Owner.Name + ')'));
            }
            return lstCompanies;        
        }
         //added to get the Lead Status
         public List<SelectOption> getStatus()
         {

            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            leadObj=new Lead();
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Lead.Status.getDescribe();
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistVal = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListEntry : picklistVal)
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getLabel(), pickListEntry.getValue()));
            }       
            return options;
         }


        // Action Methods
        public PageReference convertLead()
        {

               List<Database.LeadConvert> leadsToConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
                // Create LeadConvert object
                Database.LeadConvert converter;
                converter = new Database.LeadConvert();
                converter.setLeadId(leadSource.Id);
                converter.setOwnerId(leadSource.OwnerId);
                if(strAccountId.length() > 1)
                {
                converter.setAccountId(strAccountId); 
                }
                converter.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(createOpp);

                // Set Opportunity Name
                if(createOpp == false)
                { 
                    converter.setOpportunityName(leadSource.Company); 
                }
                LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
                converter.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
                leadsToConvert.add(converter);

                // Convert!
                Database.LeadConvertResult convertResult = Database.convertLead(converter);

                // If User dont want to create a new opportunity,it updates the existing values.
                if(createOpp == false)
                {
                    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Id=convertResult.getOpportunityId());
                    update o;
                }

                // Redirect...
                PageReference prResult;
                if(convertResult.isSuccess())
                {
                    prResult = new PageReference('/' + convertResult.getAccountId());
                    prResult.setRedirect(true);
                    return prResult;    
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
       }

}
```

My Test class  is :

```
@isTest
public with sharing class LeadConversionController_Tester
{

 static testMethod void testLeadConversion()
    {
        Profile profile1 = [SELECT id,name FROM Profile WHERE name = 'System Administrator'];
        User user1 = TestData.getNewUser(profile1.Id);

        Profile profile2 = [SELECT id,name FROM Profile WHERE name = 'Sales Operations'];
        User user2 = TestData.getNewUser(profile2.Id);

        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(user1)
        {
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId());
        }
        System.runAs(user2)
        {
            System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
            System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId());
        }

        //Create a Lead
        Lead lead=TestData.getNewLead();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(lead);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.ConvertLeadNew;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(lead.Id));
        //MultiSelectController pag = new MultiSelectController(sc);
        LeadConversionController controller=new LeadConversionController(sc);
        controller.getlstCompanyInfo();
        controller.getStatus();
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        LeadConversionController lcr=new LeadConversionController(sc);  

        // Make sure conversion was successful
       // System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Comment: And what specifically your question? If just the title then you call it like any other method

Comment: Is the `lead` from TestData.getNewLead() inserted in the database? Does it have an Id? Where does the coverage in your testLeadConversion() method top?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the method like a normal method

```
controller.convertLead();
```

It will cover your method and if you have condition then you need to set your test data such that you can pass that. There is no special syntax for `pagereference` method in test class.

**Update**
As @Eystornt pointed out you are calling this method from your constructor so the most likely reason is you are getting some exception which you can check with `system.debug`  and once you fixed that your method will be covered and you don't need to call `convertLead()` method again.

Comment: @user37095 you don't need to set any variable. Just call the method and check.

Comment: Well as in his test, in the constructor he already calls the convertLead(), it should be covered in the first place..

If the constructor doesn't go to the convertLead() in the constructor, it's because of a previous failure 

Calling directly a method that's normally already covered by the constructor is a bad practice because you don't mimic the situation, you bypass some of it

Comment: Suprised op does not get a DML not allowed error doing DML in constructor like that

Comment: @Eric I think this is the same error he is getting in test class

Answer (score 0):

If convertLead() is not covered, although you called the constructor, it's because of a failure on the previous instructions of your contructeur

The best way to know which variables you need to cover the convertLead(), try enabling the debug log for your user*. Afterwards you can run your tests and see where it fails in the debug logs.

And then you can correct it, re-run the tests, and see the results. Back and forth !

The way of Tushar is of course possible, it's straighforward, but it's not a good practice in the unit test way

*quick find box -> debug -> new debug -> select your user -> select a generous time frame (between 1 and 24 hours) -> debug level